# How to mock a synchronous lambda invocation for testing

Tags: python, pytest, moto

I have a lambda function which in turn calls another lambda function synchronously. I am trying to write tests for the parent function using pytest but I am not sure what is the best way to mock the child lambda function using moto and how does all of it come together in a test function. Can anyone please guide me here.

### Parent function

app.py

```
import boto3 

def launch_child_lambda(func_name, data):
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
    result = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=func_name,
        Payload=json.dumps(data)
    )

    return result
    
.....
#omitting code for brevity
.....


def handler(event,context):
    //some logic to be tested
    response=launch_child_lambda(func_name,data)
    //some other logic to be tested
```

Comment: I would just mock `launch_child_lambda` and specify a return value for it, then assert if it was called. Did you want your tests invoking lambdas?